# Vertically align TextBox to the center of the GridView row

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView, and inside it a few fields, here is the code to it:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GW" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="0" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="GW_RowDataBound">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="df1" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hideGridColumn" ItemStyle-CssClass="hideGridColumn">
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="df2" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hideGridColumn" ItemStyle-CssClass="hideGridColumn">
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="df3" HeaderText="Activity" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataFormatString="{0:d}">
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="BlOption" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Rating_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Width="50px" HeaderText="" RepeatLayout="Table">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="0">0</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comment" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbComment"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="Comment_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

The problem is the TextBox tbComment, it is glued to the top of the row. I tried setting the **ItemStyle-VerticalAlign** property to **Middle** or **Bottom**, but the TextBox is stuck to the top of the row.

Here is how it looks:
[image]

Can You please tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Try in this way:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comment" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbComment"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="Comment_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
           <ItemStyle  VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And check if in the page there is a css file that could interact with table style. Try to remove it.

I had a similar issue, but when I set the itemstyle as follow

```
<ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom"  />
```

I solved.

You could define a style for vertical-align like this

```
.mystyle
{vertical-align:bottom;}
```

and use when needed in this way

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comment" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbComment"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="Comment_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
           <ItemStyle  CssClass="mystyle" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thank You for the comment. I tried to add the css class, but it is still the same :(

Comment: Strange. I suggest you to create an empty page (no master page, no css file) - for testing purpose- then insert ONLY the gridview.
Then try to check if it works.
I suggest you also to try with different browser (Chrome, ie e Firefox)